# React - Draggable components with inputs lose the ability to focus when clicking that input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draggable

```
<Draggable axis="y"
      grid={[135,135]}
      onStop={this.handleStop}
      defaultPosition={{x: this.props.task.positionX, y: this.props.task.positionY,}}>
    <div id="edit-task-component">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="edit-task-form" className="edit-task-form">
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Name" value={this.state.name} required/>
        <input type="text" name="description" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Description" value={this.state.description} required/>
        <button className="btn submit-btn" type="submit">Save </button>
      </form>
    </div>
 </Draggable>
```

What happens is I will click on the input and it will focus for a split second then loses focus -- so i cant type in the input. I have to click on it a few times for it to actually focus, therefore allowing me to type in the input. How can I get it to stay focused after clicking once? I have tried setting autofocus to true after clicking the input but that didnt work either. Any ideas ?

Comment: Probably, your component is re-rendering - related also with `Draggable` IMO - ; that's why you lose focus on the input.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use `enableUserSelectHack`, this will not interfere with existing style

   eg `<Draggable enableUserSelectHack={false}>`
2. Use `cancel` prop

   eg: give any class name, it doesn't matter

   `<Draggable cancel=".just-name">
       <input className="just-name" placeholder="Add text here" />
    </Draggable>`

Answer (score 1):

Via a `handle` to enable drag is better and you can also avoid this kind of issue easily.

Here is the demo given by the official doc:

```
return (
        <Draggable
            axis="x"
            handle=".handle"
            start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
            grid={[25, 25]}
            zIndex={100}
            onStart={this.handleStart}
            onDrag={this.handleDrag}
            onStop={this.handleStop}>
            <div>
                <div className="handle">Drag from here</div>
                <div>This readme is really dragging on...</div>
            </div>
        </Draggable>
    );
```

check its [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable-custom)

> the **handle** here is a CSS selector